# ¿Como contar los valores especificos de un registro en una tabla pivot? SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Tengo el siguiente query que me genera una pivot...

```
SELECT workDayId,EmployeeName,
                    ISNULL([MX-AG14-609],0) AS [MX-AG14-609], ISNULL([MX-AG23-197],0) AS [MX-AG23-197], 
                    ISNULL([MX-AG23-196],0) AS [MX-AG23-196], ISNULL([MX-AG23-195],0) AS [MX-AG23-195],
                    ISNULL([MX-AG14-573],0) AS [MX-AG14-573], ISNULL([MX-AG14-811],0) AS [MX-AG14-811]                  
                    FROM (SELECT workDayId,EmployeeName,calif,clave 
                            FROM cteAxis_Three
                            ) P
                    PIVOT  (max(calif) 
                            FOR clave IN ([MX-AG14-609], [MX-AG23-197], [MX-AG23-196], [MX-AG23-195],
                            [MX-AG14-573], [MX-AG14-811])) AS pvt
```

Y lo siguiente es mi resultado:
[image: Resultado]

Lo que me gustaria realizar es que contara todos los valores con 0 y 1 de los registros y en una columna nueva mostrar el resultado, es decir de mi primer registro siguiendo la logica antes mencionada el resultado seria 4, del segundo igualmente seria 4 y asi sucesivamente, ¿Como podria realizar algo como esto?

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar una columna calculada donde sumas 1 si el valor es 0 o 1 y 0 en otro caso, para cada columna.

```
SELECT workDayId,EmployeeName
       , ISNULL([MX-AG14-609],0) AS [MX-AG14-609]
       , ISNULL([MX-AG23-197],0) AS [MX-AG23-197]
       , ISNULL([MX-AG23-196],0) AS [MX-AG23-196]
       , ISNULL([MX-AG23-195],0) AS [MX-AG23-195]
       , ISNULL([MX-AG14-573],0) AS [MX-AG14-573]
       , ISNULL([MX-AG14-811],0) AS [MX-AG14-811]   
       , case when ISNULL([MX-AG14-609],0) in (0,1) then 1 else 0 end
       + case when ISNULL([MX-AG23-197],0) in (0,1) then 1 else 0 end
       + case when ISNULL([MX-AG23-196],0) in (0,1) then 1 else 0 end
       + case when ISNULL([MX-AG23-195],0) in (0,1) then 1 else 0 end
       + case when ISNULL([MX-AG14-573],0) in (0,1) then 1 else 0 end
       + case when ISNULL([MX-AG14-811],0) in (0,1) then 1 else 0 end
         As Contador0y1
  from (bla, bla)
```

Comment: Y si agrego otra columna calculado pero solo contando los 1, ¿Como puedo crear otra columna para saber si los resultados de las dos columnas calculados son iguales? Porque si creo las dos no me aparecen para utilizarlas

Comment: La mecánica es la misma, solo cambia la condición a =1 y no haría falta la llamada a IsNull,.por lo que puedes prescindir de ella.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una de las razones por las que prefiero usar agregados condicionales en vez de la función PIVOT. Su versatilidad es mucho mayor y no depende de una condición general. El código puede verse más extenso, pero generarlo es solo cuestión de copiar, pegar y modificar. Al final, la columna que deseas queda mucho más sencilla.

Dejo el ejemplo junto con los datos de prueba.

```
WITH cteAxis_Three AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES( 4088232, 'Arleth Joana', 'MX-AG14-609', 2),
               ( 4088232, 'Arleth Joana', 'MX-AG23-197', 0),
               ( 4088232, 'Arleth Joana', 'MX-AG23-196', 0),
               ( 4088232, 'Arleth Joana', 'MX-AG23-195', 2),
               ( 4088232, 'Arleth Joana', 'MX-AG14-573', 1),
               ( 4088232, 'Arleth Joana', 'MX-AG14-811', 1),
               ( 985829, 'Claudia Jeanette', 'MX-AG14-609', 2),
               ( 985829, 'Claudia Jeanette', 'MX-AG23-195', 2),
               ( 4087055, 'Juan Carlos', 'MX-AG14-609', 2),
               ( 4087055, 'Juan Carlos', 'MX-AG23-197', 2),
               ( 4087055, 'Juan Carlos', 'MX-AG23-196', 2),
               ( 4087055, 'Juan Carlos', 'MX-AG23-195', 2),
               ( 4087055, 'Juan Carlos', 'MX-AG14-573', 1),
               ( 4087055, 'Juan Carlos', 'MX-AG14-811', 2),
               ( 40888231, 'Leticia', 'MX-AG14-609', 2),
               ( 40888231, 'Leticia', 'MX-AG23-197', 0),
               ( 40888231, 'Leticia', 'MX-AG23-196', 0),
               ( 40888231, 'Leticia', 'MX-AG23-195', 2),
               ( 40888231, 'Leticia', 'MX-AG14-573', 1),
               ( 40888231, 'Leticia', 'MX-AG14-811', 1),
               ( 4088233, 'Raul Gallegos', 'MX-AG14-609', 2),
               ( 4088233, 'Raul Gallegos', 'MX-AG23-197', 0),
               ( 4088233, 'Raul Gallegos', 'MX-AG23-196', 0),
               ( 4088233, 'Raul Gallegos', 'MX-AG23-195', 2),
               ( 4088233, 'Raul Gallegos', 'MX-AG14-573', 1),
               ( 4088233, 'Raul Gallegos', 'MX-AG14-811', 1))x(workDayId,EmployeeName,clave,calif )
)
SELECT  workDayId,
        EmployeeName,
        MAX( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-AG14-609' THEN calif ELSE 0 END) AS [MX-AG14-609],
        MAX( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-AG23-197' THEN calif ELSE 0 END) AS [MX-AG23-197],
        MAX( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-AG23-196' THEN calif ELSE 0 END) AS [MX-AG23-196],
        MAX( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-AG23-195' THEN calif ELSE 0 END) AS [MX-AG23-195],
        MAX( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-AG14-573' THEN calif ELSE 0 END) AS [MX-AG14-573],
        MAX( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-AG14-811' THEN calif ELSE 0 END) AS [MX-AG14-811],
        -- SUM( CASE WHEN calif IN( 1, 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Valores1y0 /* Esto solo funciona si todas las claves tienen calificación*/
        6 - SUM( CASE WHEN calif NOT IN( 1, 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Valores1y0 /* Esto funciona cuando no todas las claves tienen calificación*/
FROM cteAxis_Three
GROUP BY workDayId,
         EmployeeName
```